# body is not sent in header request in angular4 post method

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am newbie on angular2. I am trying to hit server api by post method. and body is missing in the request. So I am unable to get data in post following is my code:-

```
data = JSON.stringify({test:'check'});
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(headers);
return this.http.post(url, data, {
  headers: headers
});
```

when I checked its curl url request it is following

```
curl 'http://dev.dynamicreports.xyz.com/designer/save/chart-config?userId=2&reportId=1' -H 'Origin: http://dev.dynamicreports.xyz.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://dev.dynamicreports.xyz.com/ui-charts-designer/build/prod/' -H 'Cookie: __utma=70597123.1022822661.1496666160.1496666160.1503145923.2; __utmz=70597123.1496666160.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ga=GA1.2.1022822661.1496666160; PHPSESSID=8sq761b6op301nmvs3ds8qv501; __auc=df1847cd15c78414fc7a8e0b4e0' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"test":"check"}' --compressed
```

I have spent around 4 hours on it. Any help regarding to this will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your json in json.stringify doesn't look valid JSON format. try data=JSON.stringify({ "test":"check"});

Comment: I tried your given json format. still not resolved.

Comment: whats the issue... are you not hitting your api method or you are but with no data?...can you post your api method? and i see that you are retuning the http call, is this method returning an Observable...? If yes make sure you are subscribing to it